# Is there any way to fill a list with a large number of scriptable objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Am making a quizz game in unity, my issue is i have a large number of scriptable objects representing the questions, i started finding it hard to just drag and drop the items into a the list containing them, i tried a some solutions of the .Net but am still unable to get it working.
So my question: is there a sane quick way to populate a list of specific objects using code instead of dragging and dropping, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Resources.LoadAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html). Put all your scriptables inside `Resources/Scriptables`.

```
void Start()
{
    // Scriptable is a class of your ScriptableObject
    Scriptable[] scripts = Resources.LoadAll<Scriptable>("Scriptables"); // Scriptables is a directory inside Resources

    foreach (Scriptable s in scripts)
    {
        myList.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a casting error, saying it can't convert from Object [] to Scriptable, i tried casting it but didn't work

Comment: @Spounka Sorry for late answer, had to come back from family meeting. Check my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to drag-n-drop one by one. Select all of them, and drag onto the array/list name, unity will append them.

Comment: But, if i add remove a question, it won't update automatically, i wanted a dynamic way to do so